# Internal server error on WordPress site while checkout hosting by aws

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, woocommerce, plugins, payment-gateway

my website is giving me internal server error on checkout. When I inspect the error on checkout page under network and response it says 'there has been critical error on this website. It was working fine 2 days ago and suddenly this error appeared. I have woocommerce plug-in and payment through razorpay. My hosting is through aws. Please help.

I was trying to buy a product and while clicking on checkout I am facing this error. Internal server error. Do I contact aws for this or can I correct it in WordPress myself, please guide? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the error log yet? What does it say? (See: [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/))

Comment: Could you please tell me where can I find wordpress files and logs in aws. Do I have to use Filezilla/putty to access the files?

Comment: Yes, you can use FilleZilla or PuTTY to connect to the server. You can also use the File Explorer in cPanel (or whatever control panel your hosting provides).

Comment: This was handled by somebody at my company who left suddenly. And now I have to find out how to connect to file explorer. I do not have the pem file. And to recreate it I have to stop the current instance which I do not want to do. Is there any other way around to solve this in WordPress itself?

Comment: Not really, no. I mean, you _can_ debug WordPress from WordPress itself to some extent (eg. via Health Check & Troubleshooting's [Troubleshooting mode](https://make.wordpress.org/support/handbook/appendix/troubleshooting-using-the-health-check/)) but you can only get so far with it. It might be a good idea to reach out to a developer and have them assist you with all this.

Comment: Oh ok  thank you for all your help. You have been really kind.

Comment: If I reboot the instance will it help in any way?

Comment: I found wordpress files in wp file manager plugin, can I correct this error from here. Please help.